# How do i make my discord.py bot block people?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i don't want some people to **spam** my bot but i want my bot to **block** them but i don't know how. Since i'm a little new to coding python i have no idea how to make my bot block people or even if it's possible i don't want people to keep spamming my bot i tried to stop them but they keep adding my bot to discord servers them spamming it i have no idea why they want to spam it. Heres the example of the anti-spam log.

```
ANTI-SPAM: {name} : SPAM!!
ANTI-SPAM: {name} : SPAM!!
ANTI-SPAM: {name} : SPAM!!
ANTI-SPAM: {name} : SPAM!!
ANTI-SPAM: {name} : SPAM!!
ANTI-SPAM: {name} : SPAM!!
ANTI-SPAM: {name} : SPAM!!
ANTI-SPAM: {name} : SPAM!!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you would want to make a blacklist function, something that changes a value wherever you store your user data. Just add a `"blacklisted": false` to each user's data, then toggle that when you detect they're spamming. Then you would want to `return` if the user is blacklisted before you execute commands in your on_message.